How to Set Idle Connection Timeout in Keycloak with Quarkus on Kubernetes
I'm currently tweaking a Keycloak, 22.0.4 setup that's running on Quarkus and deployed via Kubernetes. My main challenge is figuring out how to manage idle database connections effectively. I want to set up a timeout so that these connections close themselves after being idle for a while, which I hope will help with resource management. I came across a parameter
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.idle-removal-interval  mentioned in the Quarkus Datasource Documentation, which sounds like what I need. How would I set the parameter as an environment variable in my k8s deployment or would it have any effect? If anyone here has experience with this setup or any advice on managing database connections in this scenario, I'd appreciate your insights.
currently, we kill the idle connection from the database side every 5 minutes.

You can define the environment variable in your k8s deployment yaml e.g.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/
env:
    - name: QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_IDLE_REMOVAL_INTERVAL
      value: "1M"


You can use QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_IDLE_REMOVAL_INTERVAL env variable.
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.idle-removal-interval
quarkus.datasource."datasource-name".jdbc.idle-removal-interval
The interval at which we try to remove idle connections.
Environment variable: QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_IDLE_REMOVAL_INTERVAL

Please note that OP has already included the link of the documentation from where you copy-pasted the text
